# ios long running task in background task

Tags: ios, service, long-running-processes, background-thread

In ios, it supports long running background task for certain types of apps with background modes such as App registers for location updates,App provides Voice over IP services,App plays audio,App processes Newsstand Kit downloads,App communicates using CoreBluetooth,App shares data using CoreBluetooth.
My application in ios will updload file to remote server periodically if network connection exists.It will do this process if the file is available in the particular directory.
I want to know that in which mode above my app does come under?

Comment: for me the background modes are self described. so your app will not be allowed to run in background.

Comment: @visualication Thanks for answering.It supports long running background task for newsstand Kit downloads.In my case my app uploads file.

Comment: are you downloading from newsstand? no. so your app doesn't fit...

Answer (score 1):

the background modes are very restrictive and your app doesnt fit in any category. if you want to use background downloading, try the following tutorial:

[iOS 7 SDK: Background Transfer Service](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service/)

Comment: Thanks for answering.According to the link you refer,This functionality supports only in ios7.But i want my app to be supported from ios4.I want my app to download file once it goes to background.Will i be restricted to the time limit of 10min? Or can i increase this time in order to finish my downloadeding job?